# Compiling Vim with python3 showing E370: Could not load library libpython3.7m.a

Tags: installing, plugin-python-mode, compile-vim

I have been trying to **compile Vim with python3** on my Mac for many hours, as a result, it looks fine now, as the following:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Dec 9 2018 00:37:54) macOS version Included patches: 1-573 Huge version without GUI.
+python/dyn +python3/dyn
```

but when I tried to test using `:echo(has('python3'))`, it gives 0.

And command like `:python3 print('aha!')` gives **error**:

```
E370: Could not load library libpython3.7m.a
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
```

While python2 works fine. Can anyone help me with mercy?!

Thank you so so much!

---

p.s. this is my .configure used:

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
--enable-multibyte \
--enable-rubyinterp=yes \
--enable-python3interp=yes \
--with-python3-config-dir=/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin \
--enable-pythoninterp=yes --with-python-config-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config \
--enable-luainterp=yes \
--enable-hangulinput=yes \
--enable-cscope \
--prefix=/usr/local/
```

by the way, `--with-python3-config-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin \` works the same.

Comment: Do you have specific reasons not to use the [pre-compiled MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases)? It is already compiled for python3.7 and can also be used in the terminal (`alias vim='mvim -v'`). It can be configured to use your anaconda python3 installation: https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/wiki/FAQ#how-to-use-pythonrubylua-interface-in-macvim (not tested by myself)

Comment: What surprises me, is that at the top it looks like vim is compiled with python dynamic support (`+python3/dyn`), but the name `libpython3.7m.a` looks like a lib for static linking. Try configure option `--enable-python3interp=dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

Find your dynamic python lib, for example `libpython3.6m.so.1.0`. Then put it in your `.vimrc` like this:

```
set pythonthreedll=/location/of/your/python/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
```

Of course, change the version of the library name accordingly.

Comment: I think `pythonthreedll` should be set to dynamic python lib. Your examples looks like a directory.

Comment: "/location/of/your/python/lib/" is supposed to point to the location of the 
 dynamic python lib ,not a directory. @Ralf

Comment: `set pythonthreedll=/full/path/of/python/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0` solves the issue

Answer (score -1):

You can use the file with extension `.dylib` too, In my case, I set the path to use Xcode location.

```
set pythonthreedll=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you add any further explanation?