# Vim shows error when running python3

Tags: linux, vimscript-python, installing, linux-ubuntu

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

First, I ran

```
apt-get install python3-dev ruby-dev
```

Then, I installed vim using the instructions in the [website](https://www.vim.org/git.php), using `make distclean`, `make` and `make install` (This was like the tenth time in one week that I was compiling from source. By the way, I know now that I should use checkinstall, but I already used `make install` once, so I figured I just might as well continue using it). I chose the `big` version of vim, and uncommented the lines as indicated in the Makefile file, located at the src folder.

On the Makefile, I also uncommented the necessary lines as indicted in that same file. I think there were 3 lines related to python3, I uncommented those but not the ones for python2. I also uncommented the lines for perl and ruby, because previous trials of installing python3 support had not worked properly.

**The result**

Running `vim --version` shows `-python` and `+python3/dyn` .

When I enter vim and run `: python3 import sys` or `:python3 print ('Hello')` I get the errors:

```
E370: Could not load library libpython3.7m.a
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
```

Question: How do I fix this? How do I make python3 support work properly? I have heard of using apt-get for installing vim, but I would like to avoid that for learning purposes, and because I am installing Vim on my home directory. I have also read about neovim, but for learning purposes I want to work with vim now.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44264315/8045669) to the post "Gvim cannot load my Python" says that one should copy the file python37.dll into Vim's directory. I do not know whether that works or not; but, if it does, is there really no other solution?

Comment: Duplicate of: [Compiling Vim with python3 showing E370: Could not load library libpython3.7m.a](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/18222/51), but since that one doesn't seem to have any useful answers I'll leave this one open. That answer does have a potentially useful tidbit of information: try locating `libpython3.7m.a` (or `libpython3.7.a`) and set `pythonthreedll` to the path of that.